# which is the probability that $Y_1>Y_2$ with $Y_1, Y_2$ i.i.d

Tags: probability, iid

I think that the answer is 0.5, independently of the common distribution of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Attempt to a proof, assuming continuous random variables:

$P(Y_1>Y_2)=\int_{\Omega}f_{Y_1,Y2}(y_1,y_2)dy_1dy_2=\int_{\mathbf {R}} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{y_1} f_Y(y_2)dy_2 \right) f_Y(y_1)  dy_1 = \int_{\mathbf {R}} F_Y(y_1) f_Y(y_1)  dy_1 $

Now, integrating by parts:

$ \int_{\mathbf {R}} F_Y(y) f_Y(y)  dy = \left[(F_Y(y))^2\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \int_{\mathbf {R}} f_Y(y) F_Y(y) dy$

(EDITED because some users didn't understand the equation layout)

This implies that

$ 2\int_{\mathbf {R}} f_Y(y) F_Y(y) dy= \left[(F_Y(y))^2\right]_{-\infty}^{+\infty} = 1-0 \implies \int_{\mathbf {R}} f_Y(y) F_Y(y) dy =0.5 $

Is this correct? Does it hold for generic random variables too? With *generic* I mean $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ not necessarily continous, but still i.i.d.

Comment: Counter-example: If both are constant random variables, the probability that one is larger is zero.

Comment: right, so it doesn't hold for _generic_ random variables. Does it hold for continous random variables, though? In other words, is my "proof" correct?

Comment: If the r.v.s are strictly continuous, than they can be monotonically transformed into $U(0,1)$ variates.  Monotonicity implies that iff $y_1 > y_2$, $u_1 > u_2$ where $u_1 = F_{Y_1}(y_1)$ etc.  So if you can prove it for $U(0,1)$ variates, you've proved it for all strictly continuous variates.

Comment: Because the $Y_i$ are iid, $\Pr(Y_1\gt Y_2)=\Pr(Y_2\gt Y_1)$. By continuity, $\Pr(Y_1=Y_2)=0$. By the axiom of Total Probability, these three quantities sum to $1$.  Now solve.

Comment: @whuber , how do you prove that $Pr(Y_1>Y_2)=Pr(Y_2>Y_1)$, given that the $Y_i$ are i.i.d.? If you write these two probabilities as integrals of the joint pdf, then your proof is the same as mine. If there's another (simpler) way to prove it, please let me know, I'd be very interested. BTW, $Pr(Y_1=Y_2)=0$ derives from the fact that $A=\{(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbf{R}^2 : y_1=y_2\}$ has measure 0, so the integral of $f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)$ over $A$ is 0, correct?

Comment: It's immediate: because the $Y_i$ are iid, you must get the same probabilities when you relabel them.  Switching the labels $1$ and $2$ does the trick.  No integration is needed--this is reasoning from the most basic possible principles.  The actual mathematics--as well as the key insight--lies in the assertion that the event $Y_1=Y_2$ has zero probability, and that comes down to what you write about it having Lebesgue measure zero and the definition of (joint) continuity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three probabilities under consideration: $P\{Y_1 > Y_2\}$,
$P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}$, and $P\{Y_1 = Y_2\}$. The sum of these three is
$1$, and it *must be* that 
$$P\{Y_1 > Y_2\} = P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}. \tag{1}$$
One way to argue is to use *symmetry*, or fancier words such as 
*exchangeable* random variables. All of these essentially reduce to
the argument that *any* alleged proof that anyone devises to show that $P\{Y_1 > Y_2\} > P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}$ can be changed to a proof that
$P\{Y_1 > Y_2\} < P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}$ simply by interchanging
$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ wherever they occur in the claimed proof.
Since $P\{Y_1 > Y_2\}$ cannot be simultaneously be both
larger than and also
smaller than $P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}$
the alleged proof cannot be a valid proof at all: it *must*
be the case that $(1)$ is true.

Now, as has been pointed out several times in the comments, $(1)$
*does not imply* that 
$$P\{Y_1 > Y_2\} = P\{Y_2 > Y_1\}  = \frac 12 \tag{2}$$
unless we can also show that $P\{Y_1 = Y_2\} = 0$. A standard
counterexample to $(2)$ is the case of discrete random variables
for which
$$P\{Y_1 = Y_2\} =  \sum_{y} P\{Y_1 = y\}P\{Y_2 = y\} 
= \sum_y \left(P\{Y_1 = y\}\right)^2 > 0.$$
On the other hand, for *continuous* (iid) random variables,
$P\{Y_1 = Y_2\} = 0$ as you already say you know (cf. your comment
addressed to whuber), and so you can assert $(2)$ without
needing to go through any integrations whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, thanks: accepted your answer, which corresponds to whuber's comment.When you talk about alleged proofs, you are using _reductio ad absurdum_, right? You're not referring to my proof, which doesn't state that $P\{Y_1>Y_2\}>P\{Y_2>Y_1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to answer it: $Y_2$ and $Y_1$ are numbered arbitrarily (since they come from the same distribution). Thus it would make no sense to argue that, say the probability that $Y_1>Y_2$ is $0.6$, because the same argument would imply that the probability that $Y_2>Y_1$ is $0.6$. But plainly that's a contradiction.

Comment: Except, of course, if Y1 and Y2 have some singularities (single real values with a non zero probability) For instance, if Y is a measurement with an instrument that does fail to detect a signal in half of the cases, you have 0.25 chance both measurements are zero, thus equal.

Comment: Another way to understand what @DirkHorsten is getting at is to observe that there is no contradiction at all in supposing $\Pr(Y_1\gt Y_2)=0.4$, say.  This indicates your argument is incomplete.

Comment: But still, in many cases there are no singularities, so I upvoted the answer anyway.